# Right way to handle a predefined set of salutations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just started with my first real rails app.

I have a predefined set of salutations ("Herr", "Frau, "Herr und Frau") for my customer model.
The app has to deal with an export to a csv file where "Herr" has to be the integer 1, "Frau" 2 and "Herr und Frau" = 3.

Therefore I thought it would be clever to save that salutation as an integer and simply add an  salutation_readable method to my customer model like this:

```
def salutation_readable
    case salutation
    when 1
      "Herr"
    when 2
      "Frau"
    when 3
      "Herr und Frau"
    end
end
```

to display the salutation in my views.

In the customer form partial I added:

```
<%= f.select(:salutation, options_for_select([['Herr', 1], ['Frau', 2], ['Herr und Frau', 3]])) %>
```

Everything works as expected, except the customer edit view where the preselected value is always the first entry and not my saved one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options_for_select takes a second parameter as the default selected option.

```
<%= f.select(:salutation, options_for_select([['Herr', 1], ['Frau', 2], 
['Herr und Frau', 3]], @customer.salutation_readable)) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer.. I've read that in the documentation but for whatever reason didn't think of it Oo
Btw it was `<%= f.select(:salutation, options_for_select([['Herr', 1], ['Frau', 2], 
['Herr und Frau', 3]], @customer.salutation)) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Surely the problem with this approach is that you are defining the relationship between salutation and id in two places. That is, if you decide to add 'Doktor' at a later date, you could do so like this:

```
def salutation_readable
  case salutation
  when 1
    "Herr"
  when 2
    "Frau"
  when 3
    "Doktor"
  when 4
    "Herr und Frau"
  end
end
```

But not update the select, or update the select like this:

```
<%= f.select(:salutation, options_for_select([['Herr', 1], ['Frau', 2], ['Herr und Frau', 3], ['Doktor', 4], @customer.salutation_readable)) %>
```

In either case, you end up with an inconsistency between the form select and salutation_readable.

Personally, I'd be tempted to store the salutation as a string.

If you must store it via an id then I would define the relationship between id and salutation in the model, and then use that definition everywhere.

```
class User

  def self.salutations = {
    1 => 'Herr',
    2 => 'Frau',
    3 => 'Herr und Frau',
    4 => 'Doktor'
  }

  def salutation_readable
    self.class.salutations[salutation.to_i]
  end

end
```

Then in your view you could do this:

```
<%= f.select(:salutation, User.salutations.to_a.collect(&:reverse))
```

It then also becomes easier to extend, so that User.salutations calls a separate Salutation object or a translation file for example.